# Multiple fetch statements in componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

First I used `componentWillMount()` to populate the `articles` property (this worked, no problem). I iterated over these values to show different images/text on certain containers/components.

The problem I have now is that I now also want to use `componentWillMount` to fill the  `background` property with a single image. I think I was okay using the `''` instead of `[]` but I am not sure how to make these two API calls.

I have done enough research to know that my answer probably lies in promises, but I could not extrapolate from the examples how they would apply to my particular problem. Any ideas?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    articles: [],
    backgroundz: '',
  };
}


componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/getArticles')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (json) {
      this.setState({
        articles: json,
      });
  }.bind(this));

  fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/getBackground')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (json) {
    this.setState({
      backgroundz: json,
    });
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Instead of `.bind(this)` you really should use arrow functions.

Comment: You probably will need to clone the unaltered parts of your state in each `setState` call

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to perform initial AJAX requests in componentDidMount, as per [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Other than that, the syntax for these fetch requests is a little off. There also isn't a reason to pass props into a constructor or super if they won't be used in the constructor, which you should generally avoid anyway. I'd refactor it to look like this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    articles: [],
    backgroundz: '',
  };
}


componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/getArticles')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(articles => this.setState({ articles });

  fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/getBackground')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(backgroundz => this.setState({ backgroundz });

  }
}
```

Comment: You could also define it as `async componentDidMount()` to use `await`